# Ionic how to change ion-content > main style?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want set custom padding to left and right. How can i do this ?

[I can see from inspect like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uyx2.png)

EDİT: I solved the problem when i added "padding" to ion-content tag.

```
<ion-content padding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct method**

you should use ionic classes.

add

```
ion-padding
```

class to **ion-content**

*The default amount of padding to be applied is 16px and is set by the --ion-padding variable.*

inside your **.scss** file you can edit ion-padding variable.

to edit: top, left, right or bottom padding, read ionic css utils guide.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities

Comment: i added "ion-padding" to ion-content tag and it worked

Comment: Next time before ask a question, please try to google it first. Anyway, glad to help you

Comment: You are right. I searched but the result I found was just adding "padding".

Comment: It's because you didn't know what to search. Also read full Documentation of Ionic before work with it.